# Try to delete `Ensure` from my project

Tags: c#, asp.net

For `Ensure.GreaterThanZero(timeout, nameof(timeout));` I try `if (timeout <= 0) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(timeout));`, but it show error

> Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TimeSpan' and 'int'

Answer (score 6):

The `timeout` variable is a [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) (apparently), and as such `<= 0` doesn't work *because* a `TimeSpan` has [no `operator <=(TimeSpan, int)` defined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5).

You have three options, create a [new 'zero-time' `TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromticks(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (timeout <= TimeSpan.FromTicks(0))
```

Or compare the [`TimeSpan.Ticks` with 0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (timeout.Ticks <= 0)
```

Or, [as Panagiotis Kanavos said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43979695/4564272), use [`TimeSpan.Zero`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.zero(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (timeout <= TimeSpan.Zero)
```

Answer (score 6):

The error message is clear - you can't compare a [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) value with an integer.

Try [TimeSpan.Zero](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.zero(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
if (timeout<=TimeSpan.Zero) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(timeout));
```